# Model not being executed when router change

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i'm building my first emberJS application, just started learning yesterday about the framework to day i started getting into some problems that couldn't find a solution for... this is one of them smile

i have a search result: http://rommelxcastro.github.io/batarang/#/stocks/search/goo if you click on one of the item you should go to a new route that is something like (http://rommelxcastro.github.io/batarang/#/stocks/STATNOR/1225_70109301_2), this is suppose to show all the info, no problem with this, the problem is that when the route is loaded i need to load some more information for this specific item and update the model but looks like the model inside the route is not being executed, idk why or the info is not being updated. this is my route code: https://github.com/rommelxcastro/batarang/blob/develop/app/scripts/routes/stock_route.js#L17

thanks for the help, if you didn't understand something, please let me know

Comment: There are some additional issues with your route's model, I'm not sure about all of the use cases of it, but in certain cases on https://github.com/rommelxcastro/batarang/blob/develop/app/scripts/routes/stock_route.js#L34 you will return undefined since the code that populates stock is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

Change your link-to to send the name (or whatever unique identifier you want to send) instead of the object.  When you send an object to the link-to helper it assumes you're sending it the record itself, so it skips the model hook.

```
 {{#link-to 'stock' source_name }}
     <h4>{{ source_name }} - <small>{{ name }}</small> </h4>
 {{/link-to}}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @kingpin2k, unfortunately my route requires 2 parameters (:source_name/:code), i haven't found a specific way to deal with this, thanks

Comment: You can send multiple ids to a link-to  {{#link-to 'foo' compositeId1 compositeId2}} go to foo {{/link-to}}, here's an example http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bufotiyi/1/edit

Comment: weird, that didn't work for me, i had to change the url structure, thanks for your help